# How to get precipitation (rainfall) from Yahoo Weather via Temboo?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

could anybody please tell me how to obtain the precipitation (rainfall) from Yahoo Weather via Temboo?

Comment: Have you attempted to look it up?

Comment: Yes. I even checked with Temboo but they have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Temboo.

Yahoo's response body doesn't include data for precipitation. However, you can get it from the Weather Underground API. Here's a snippet from a response:

```
"UV":"1","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
"precip_1hr_in":"0.00",
"precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
"precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0 mm)",
"precip_today_in":"0.00",
"precip_today_metric":"0",
```

If you want to use The Weather Underground API via Temboo, you should take a look at our HTTP Choreos - they let you connect to any API that we don't currently provide first-class support for:

https://temboo.com/library/Library/Utilities/HTTP/